# Understand SVG viewport

Tags: svg, viewport

I'm trying to understand the SVG viewport. Why are these three examples so different?

```css
svg {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  </svg>

  <svg width="200" height="200">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: First svg: by default has a width="300" height="150" and a viewBox to match: 0 0 300 150. The second svg has width="200" height="200" and a viewBox to match; 0 0 200 200. The third svg has viewBox="0 0 200 200". Since there is no width and height attributes will scale to take all the width available - in this case 100vw. The aspect ratio will be preserved and in this case the height will be the same as the width i.e 100vw

Answer (score 2):

- The first example is missing a width and height. The CSS specification says that replaced elements missing width and height values fallback to 300px x 150px so you'd see the top left 300 x 150 px of whatever you're drawing onto the canvas.
- The second example has width and height so you'd see that part of the canvas.
- The third example also has no width/height but oddly we're now going to use the 100% x 100% lacuna values for the width/height because we have a usable aspect ratio from the viewBox. The viewBox also scales the 200 x 200 internal co-ordinate system to fix into that canvas so everything looks bigger.